# Модифицировать ссылку на странице

Tags: javascript, ссылки

Задача не простая, может кто сможет помочь.

Есть ссылки вида:

```
https://site.com
https://site.com/categories
https://site.com/categories/post
```

А нужно добавить к ним в конце `.html`

Ссылки с другими доменами не менять!

Answer (score 2):

`a[href^="https://site.com"]` селектор берет все якоря, у которых href начинается (`^=`) с  указанной строки.

```js
let links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="https://site.com"]');

for (let link of links) {
  link.href = link.href.replace(/\/?$/, ".html");
  // $ — конец строки.
  // ? — совпадение 0 или 1 раз. Если в конце строки есть / - удалит и его.
  
  console.log(link.href);
}
```

```html
<a href="https://site.com">Test</a>
<a href="https://site.com/categories">Test</a>
<a href="https://site.com/categories/">Test</a>
<a href="https://site.com/categories/post">Test</a>

<a href="https://google.com#q=https://site.com">Test</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает отлично!

Comment: Думал разберусь, но что-то не соображу. Нужно сделать так чтобы все ссылки `https://domain.com` или `https://domain.com/14526-hello` заменялись на `https://site.com/g/?lnk=https://domain.com` и `https://site.com/g/?lnk=https://domain.com/14526-hello`

Comment: @Tenk `link.href = "https://site.com/g/?lnk=" + link.href;`